# VB6 to c# code LSet Mid

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

I am trying to convert the VB6 code to C# and looking to understand LSet and Mid, below is my vb6 and C# code , does the conversion look fine

```
strPrint = ""
strPAD = Space(12)
LSet strPAD = Mid(Trim(rsVoucher.Fields("Reference")) & "", 1, 12)
strPrint = strPrint & strPAD & " "                                 ' 13




string reference = vouchDr["REFERENCE"].ToString();
string temp_reference = reference;
if (reference.Length > 12)
{
     temp_reference = reference.Substring(0, 12) + "";
}
strPAD = temp_reference + (new string(' ', 12 - temp_reference.Length));
strPrint = strPAD + " "; //13
```

Comment: It will work, but looks ugly -it is another language with another libraries.
string.Format("{0,-13}",vouchDr["REFERENCE"]).Substring(0,13);
Makes the same, but looks better

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for: 'PadLeft' Method of string objects.

your code will look like ....

```
string temp_reference = reference.PadLeft(12, ' ');

if (temp_reference.Length > 12)
{
     temp_reference = temp_reference.Substring(0, 12) + "";
}

temp_reference += " ";
```